# Python: HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Bad Behavior

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-error

I am trying to read a web page to extract contents from it. Please find below the code.

```
url = "http://www.sanjamar.com/product-categories/bar/bar-tools/"    
html = urlopen(url).read()    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup)
```

The last time I used with a different website, it worked. This time its throwing the following error.

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-ccdefd422a61> in <module>()
      1 url = "http://www.sanjamar.com/product-categories/bar/bar-tools/"
----> 2 html = urlopen(url).read()
      3 soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
      4 print(soup)

C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, 
timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, 
data, timeout)
    530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 532             response = meth(req, response)
    533 
    534         return response

C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, 
request, response)
    640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    641             response = self.parent.error(
--> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 
    644         return response

C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, * 
args)
    568         if http_err:
    569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + 
orig_args
--> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
    571 
    572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it 
    makes

 C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, 
 chain,    
    kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, 
req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Bad Behavior
```

I guess the issue is the website is blocking python. If not please let me know a solution.

Thanks

Comment: It looks from the error message that the website is running [a plugin called Bad Behavior](http://bad-behavior.ioerror.us/about/) and is detecting your web scraping as spam or bot like. Are you limiting the number of times you call the web page in some way, like using the [ratelimiter module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ratelimiter)? If not, that might be worth trying to see if the site stops treating your requests as spam.

Comment: I could get through it

    `import http.client`
    `conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.sanjamar.com")`
    `conn.request("GET", "/")`
    `r1 = conn.getresponse()`
    `print(r1.status, r1.reason)`